# When a creaky door briefly makes no sound, has the sound simply gone into the ultrasonic pitch range?

Tags: acoustics, rotation

Sometimes, when I’m opening a creaky door, it will only creak for part of the motion; being, apparently, silent for small portions of the turn. However, I’ve noticed that the pitch of the creaking sound and the speed with which the door rotates always increase before the silence occurs.

My running theory is that the pitch of the sound coming from the creaky door is directly proportional to the door’s angular speed, and that the “silent” portions of the motion are really just as loud, but beyond the range of human hearing. Is this true?

Comment: Unfortunately it's just as likely that it could have started slipping without catching and thus makes little to no actual sound, you'd have to use an ultrasound rated detector to settle the issue.

Comment: @Triatticus would both the ultrasonic situation, and the “slipping without catching“ situation seem the same to a human observer?

Comment: Well if the idea is you can't hear it then I'd say that at that point they would seem the same. But you may have all the tools to make your own experiment to test your hypothesis, sound recording apps on phones I believe can record above human hearing range though I'm not entirely sure

Comment: If the 'sound' becomes ultrasonic, I'd expect a non-sharp transition to inaudibility, via an almost unbearably high pitched note becoming fainter and fainter. This is because the ear's high frequency cut-off is not sharp.